# Exernal dependency for javaplanner

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, external-dependencies

I have a dependency for javaplanner in my project.
My POM dependency for javaplanner as below:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javaplanner</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaplanner</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

While building the project I am getting error that not able to resolve the dependency.

Pleas find the below error logs:

```
Failure to find javaplanner:javaplanner:jar:1.5
in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
elapsed or updates are forced
-> [Help 1]
```

I have tried to get the dependency and found that the javaplanner has discontinued.

I searched over the internet to find external links to downlod the jar file, but not able to find the same.

Could anyone please share a link to download the dependency for javaplanner?

Appreciated!!!!

Comment: Please share the error logs as you could see and any relevant source to get to know which javaplanner in your context is in question.

Comment: @nullpointer I have added the error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these links, these I found from google so cannot comment on quality of jar. Start with 2nd one first.

https://dhtmlx-javaplanner.soft32.com

https://www.download3k.com/Install-DHTMLX-JavaPlanner.html

https://dhtmlx-javaplanner.soft112.com

https://www.download.hr/software-dhtmlx-javaplanner.html

Comment: Thanks Amit. I got it from the second links

Comment: I would expect google searches and links to them not being a part of an answer. But a better explanation to why one should use it. Otherwise the question too be off topic.